# Highlight button when radio button is checked

Tags: jquery, html, css, button

I am trying to highlight a save button once one of three radio buttons are checked.

Then once the user clicks the save button, it should lose the highlight class and return to normal, the user can also click the cancel button and the save button will lose the highlight effect.

```
 $('label').click(function() {
   $('.greyBtn').addClass('glow');
   if ($('.greyBtn').data('clicked', true)) {
     $('greyBtn').removeClass('glow');
   } else if ($('.cancel').data('clicked', true)) {
     $('greyBtn').remove.Class('glow');
   }
 });
```

Right now it only highlights the save button upon radio button check, it will not lose the class again, when i click the buttons.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Staehren/pt767mcm/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use click functions to do this.
here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pt767mcm/2/)

```
$('label').click(function() {
   $('.greyBtn').addClass('glow');
 });
   $('.greyBtn').click(function() {
   $(this).removeClass('glow');
   });
  $('.cancel').click(function() {
   $('.greyBtn').removeClass('glow');
  });
```

Comment: happy to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the setter of `data()` in the `if` statement instead of the getter. 
There's also a couple of syntax issues in your code.

To do this more effectively you can hook to the `change` event of the radios and use `toggleClass()`, like this:

```js
$('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
    $('.greyBtn').toggleClass('glow', this.checked);
});
```

```css
@keyframes glowing {
    0% {
        background-color: #B20000;
        box-shadow: 0 0 3px #B20000;
    }
    50% {
        background-color: #FF0000;
        box-shadow: 0 0 20px #FF0000;
    }
    100% {
        background-color: #B20000;
        box-shadow: 0 0 3px #B20000;
    }
}

.glow {
    animation: glowing 1500ms infinite;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input name="radio" type="radio">One</label><br/>
<label><input name="radio" type="radio">Two</label>
<label><input name="radio" type="radio">Three</label>

<input type="submit" value="Gem" class="greyBtn" />
<input type="submit" value="Cancel" class="cancel" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create the 'click' event for the button outside the "$('label').click" event?

```
 $('.greyBtn').click(function() {
      $('greyBtn').removeClass('glow'); 
 });
```